# How can I set a new message for a share dialog on a canvas app?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using Facebook's JavaScript SDK I am trying to open a share dialog from **within a canvas app**, which I am able to do fine.  However, when I try to amend the message that gets sent along with it, I'm unable to get things working.

I'm aware I can change the message using meta tags within the document itself, as Facebook scrapes the page on the link to grab `og:*` tags from the `head` of the doc, but the message I want to share is specific to this user's experience, for example: "I just scores 9/10 on this quiz, can you do any better?".

I have set up an action, object and story, which are being linked in fine.  Below is my code, which isn't changing the message:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'the-dog-breed-quiz:take',         
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        quiz:'https://apps.facebook.com/removed',
        message: 'I scored 15 out of a possible 20 on the Test quiz. Can you do any better?'
    })
}, function(response){});
```

Comment: You are not allowed to specify the _message_ part of any share or post for the user, they have to type it in themselves. But it looks like you are confusing the _message_ with the object title/description here anyway. If you want an Open Graph Story that contains information specific to that user, then you should create an individual Open Graph _object_ for this. If you don’t want to host that object yourself (meaning an HTML page with OG meta tags), then you can use the [Object API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api) to create objects dynamically.

Comment: So are you saying I need to create a page with the relevant `og:*` tags within, and then use that as the `quiz` value?

Comment: Open Graph Stories alway consist of an action _and_ an object that action is performed upon. And since you want users to share their individual quiz result, you want an individual object for each user (or even mutiple objects for one user, if they take your test multiple times.) What you can do if you don’t want to host those objects yourself, I already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and piecing things together I have the following solution.

The process is thus:

- Have a button to be clicked.  This is a must, as you'll need to provide proof of user interaction in order to show a dialog.
- Ensure you have `publish_actions` permission at point of login
- Create a user action.  I did this using JS SDK, see below code.
- Take the ID from the user action and reference that as part of the UI call

.

```
FB.api(
    'me/objects/your-app-namespace:quiz',
    'post',
    {'object': {
        'og:title': 'Blah blah',
        'og:type': 'your-app-namespace:quiz',
        'og:image': 'https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png',
        'og:description': 'keyboard mashdfhg nfkg kfd hg',
        'fb:app_id': 'removed'
    }},

    function(response) {    
        // handle the response
        FB.ui({
            method: 'share_open_graph',
            action_type: 'your-app-namespace:take',
            action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                quiz:response.id,
            })
        }, function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
);
```